Manipulate string in DBT's macro with Jinja2
I am trying to create a dbt macro that can load a table from the macro's arguments. I can do it when I specify input directly, e.g.: ref('data_categories') (data_categories is a real table name). However, my problem occurs when manipulating the string to pass to ref. Below are my error function and an error during compiling time.
    {% macro my_fnc(prefix=None) %}
        
        {% set load_table %}
            {% if prefix is defined %}
                {{ prefix }} ~ '_data_categories'
            {% else %}
                'data_categories'
            {% endif %}
        {% endset %}
    
        {% set sql_statement %}
            select *
            from {{ ref( load_table  ) }}
        {% endset %}
        
       ...

    {% endmacro %}

My error:
Model X depends on a node named '
          
              'data_categories'
          
      ' which was not found

Because the error message is not clear and there is a symbol ' and spaces, my thinking now is there is something wrong in {{ ref( load_table  ) }} because Jinja couldn't understand the intention of load_table My naive question: What is a correct to pass my defined table to ref

I'd start running a dbt compile of the model, and see what your Jinja is compiling to.

Using a block set command is going to give you all sorts of issues with whitespaces, return carriages, etc. You can remove whitespace by changing your tag declarations from {% ... %} to {%- ... -%}. But in your case, I would remove the block set tag completely:
    {% macro my_fnc(prefix=None) %}
        
        {% if prefix is defined %}
            {% set load_table = prefix ~ '_data_categories' %}
        {% else %}
            {% set load_table = 'data_categories' %}
        {% endif %}
    
        {% set sql_statement %}
            select *
            from {{ ref( load_table  ) }}
        {% endset %}
        
       ...

    {% endmacro %}

